# Android APK generated via Android Studio is missing MANIFEST.MF file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-signing

I have an android project using android studio 3.6.1.  When I generate an apk from Android Studio, the generated APK file is missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.  However,  when I build the apk via console, everything is working properly.

I am not sure what settings in build.gradle controls creation of this file and when it is created.  Any help in this respect would be appreciated.

Following in my build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09'
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09'
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply from: '../config/quality.gradle'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.spotbugs'

    project.extensions.extraProperties.set('SpotBugsTask', com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask)

    // loads the current project's local settings file
    Properties localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = project.file('../local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localProperties.load(new FileInputStream(localPropertiesFile))
        localProperties.list(System.out)
    }

    android {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
            targetCompatibility 1.8
        }
        tasks.withType(Test) {
            // pass the proxy configuration to the gradle test executor
            systemProperty "http.proxyHost", System.getProperty('http.proxyHost')
            systemProperty "http.proxyPort", System.getProperty('http.proxyPort')
            systemProperty "http.proxyUser", System.getProperty('http.proxyUser')
            systemProperty "http.proxyPassword", System.getProperty('http.proxyPassword')
            systemProperty "https.proxyHost", System.getProperty('https.proxyHost')
            systemProperty "https.proxyPort", System.getProperty('https.proxyPort')
            systemProperty "https.proxyUser", System.getProperty('https.proxyUser')
            systemProperty "https.proxyPassword", System.getProperty('https.proxyPassword')
        }

        def appName = "app_name"
        def appIdSuffix = ""
        if (project.hasProperty('appSuffix') && appSuffix ==~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/) {
            println("Appending suffix: " + appSuffix)
            appIdSuffix = appSuffix
        }

        compileSdkVersion parent.ext.androidCompileSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion parent.ext.androidBuildToolsVersion

        testOptions {
            unitTests {
                includeAndroidResources = true
            }
            animationsDisabled = true
            unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
            unitTests.all {
                maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1
                systemProperty "testResponse", "${projectDir}/src/testServerDebug/res/raw"
                testLogging {
                    showStackTraces = true
                    exceptionFormat = "full"
                    events 'passed', 'failed', 'skipped'
                }
                maxHeapSize = "4g"
            }
            execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
        }

        android {
            lintOptions {
                warning "TrustAllX509TrustManager"
            }
        }

        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/production/kotlin'
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/server/kotlin'
            test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
            test.java.srcDirs += 'src/testServerDebug/kotlin'
            test.java.srcDirs += 'src/testServerDebug/java'
            androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
            exclude 'META-INF/app_serverRelease.kotlin_module'
        }


        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion parent.ext.androidMinSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion parent.ext.androidTargetSdkVersion
            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.0"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }

        signingConfigs {

            debug {
                storeFile file("keystore.jks")
                storePassword "test"
                keyAlias "test"
                keyPassword "test"
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                debuggable false
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                multiDexEnabled false
                if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                } else {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                }

                proguardFile getDefaultProGuardFile('proguard-release.pro')
                proguardFile getDefaultProGuardFile('proguard-androidx.pro')
                proguardFile 'proguard-project.pro'
            }

            debug {
                testCoverageEnabled false
                ext.enableCrashlytics = false
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }

        flavorDimensions "default"
        productFlavors {
            production {
                dimension "default"
            }

            server {
                dimension "default"
                applicationIdSuffix ".server" + appIdSuffix
                resValue "string", appName, appIdSuffix
            }
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            preDexLibraries false
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        serverImplementation('com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.8.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
            exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
            exclude group: 'org.ow2.asm', module: 'asm'
        }

        def nav_version = "1.0.0"

        implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
        implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

        implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0"
        implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0"
        implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutine"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutine"


        kaptAndroidTest 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.12'
        testImplementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:1.6.2'
        testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.2'
        testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2'
        testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2'
        testImplementation('org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2') {
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
        }
        testImplementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'

        testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19') {
            exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
        }
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
        testImplementation('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        }
        testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
        testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        testImplementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6'
        androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.capitalone.easyscreenshots:easyscreenshots:1.1.0@aar'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.jraska:falcon:2.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0') {
            exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        }
        androidTestImplementation('androidx.test:runner:1.2.0') {
            exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        }
        androidTestImplementation('androidx.test:rules:1.2.0') {
            exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        }
        androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0') {
            exclude module: 'design'
            exclude module: 'support-annotations'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
            exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
            exclude module: 'appcompat'
        }
        androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0') {
            exclude module: 'design'
            exclude module: 'support-annotations'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
            exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
            exclude module: 'appcompat'
        }
        androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.2.0') {
            exclude module: 'design'
            exclude module: 'support-annotations'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
            exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
            exclude module: 'appcompat'
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you post your gradle file? Also, does that happen only when you build from Android studio? What about building the APK from terminal?

Comment: When I build via terminal, it contains all the files.  it's only via Android Studio that it doesn't contain the said file.

Comment: I also noticed that CERT.RSA and CERT.SF files are also not there.

Comment: Did you find fix for it ? issue is only  when app is built using gradle plugin >= v3.6.0 and gradle version >= v5.6.4

Comment: There is a ticket raised on the Google issue tracker for this bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168013083

Comment: @mmBs Yes it was opened by me. No response from Google yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. It didn't work through Android Studio nor when building directly from terminal. I've resolved it by adding

```
signingConfigs {
    myDefaultSigningConfigs {
        ...
        v1SigningEnabled true
    }
}
```

I hope it helps in your case.